# Magento - addStoreFilter not working?

Tags: magento

When getting a product collection in Magento, I would expect the StoreFilter to do just that, filter by the current store. But I can't get it to work.

Say I have 2 stores set up like so: [image]

And both stores have a different root category. Main Store is the default sample data, Store2 has just one product I added. I would have thought that using the store filter, only products within the root category of the current store would show up. But I'm getting every product showing. I'm testing this by placing the following in my category view template:

```
$store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->addStoreFilter($store_id)
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_testproductCollection->load();
foreach($_testproductCollection as $_testproduct){ 
echo $this->htmlEscape($_testproduct->getName()); 
};
```

If I echo the store ID, it's giving me the correct number. I have only one product in Store 2, so why am I getting every product from all stores returned? I can set every product in Main Store to not show in Store2 and then add a visibility filter, but that would take forever.

Also, I just noticed, if I echo the products store ID, I get the current ID, not the store it's assigned to:

```
echo $_testproduct->getStoreId()
```

What's going on?

**UPDATE (April 8 2011):**
OK, so I tried joining the fields so that the store_id is included (as suggested below), the section of code **{{table}}.store_id = 1** is just setting all the products to have a store_id of 1. How can I just get the store_id associated with the product?

```
$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$_testproductCollection->joinField('store_id', 'catalog_category_product_index', 'store_id', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.store_id = 1', 'left');
$_testproductCollection->getSelect()->distinct(true);
$_testproductCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();

foreach($_testproductCollection as $_testproduct){  
echo $this->htmlEscape($_testproduct->getName())."<br/>"; 
echo "STORE IS ".$_testproduct->getData('store_id')."<br/>";
};
```

If I check the **catalog_category_product_index** table of my db, the store_id's are correct.

Comment: what version of magento?

Comment: Is there any solution so far, having the same problem. I absolutely need the productcollection of a special storeview. I have one website, 4 storeviews (2 languages of 2 shops) which devide some categories and some not. Im new to magento so i do not understand the joinField() thing. Is there any example or another solution.

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078752/magento-addcategoryfilter-filtering-product-collection-by-root-category - I ended up filtering by root category instead.

Comment: Filtering by root is very buggy, so back to this now trying to figure out if it'll work...see above for updates

Comment: my solution for category filter by store )

[http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284088/1266559][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19284088/1266559

Comment: Where did $storeId on line 3 of the test code come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think this works, haven't tested too much but seems to have done the trick. You need to first get your stores root category id, then join some fields so you have access to the products "category_id", then filter using that:

```
$_rootcatID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $_rootcatID))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_testproductCollection->load();

foreach($_testproductCollection as $_testproduct){ 
    echo $this->htmlEscape($_testproduct->getName())."<br/>"; 
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`$_testproductCollection` should look like this `$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addStoreFilter()`.

If You print `SELECT` from that collection You will see that there ain't any store column, so `addStoreFilter()` can't apply `WHERE`.

You should use `joinField()` on Your collection and add `store_id` column from `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table.

**EDIT**

Sorry to keep You waiting ;)

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->joinField('store_id', 'catalog_category_product_index', 'store_id', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.store_id = 1', 'left');
$collection->getSelect()->distinct(true);
```

This should do the trick, but just to be sure, please check if you're getting right products :)

Comment: The `addStoreFilter` doesn't add any check for the root category of a store or anything like that, it only filters the non-global attributes of a product. This only has an effect on products that have been edited when the "Choose Store View" box was used in admin. `store_id` is not an attribute in it's own right, it is only a property of other attributes.

Comment: That's why i suggested `joinField()` and shortened resource model loading call.

Comment: I was thinking then that maybe filtering by root category was the way to go, as that's pretty much accomplishing the same thing, but that doesn't seem to work either - see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078752/magento-addcategoryfilter-filtering-product-collection-by-root-category

Comment: Could you perhaps give an example of how to join the fields? I've found a few examples online but haven't managed to patch together something that works!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId); 
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku','price'));
```

Comment: This is especially helpful when you are selecting/filtering by store specific attributes. Using `->setStoreId($storeId)` doesn't seem to produce the correct query in that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think

You don't need to do any joins as the magento's setStoreId() will work.

```
 $collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
->getCollection()
->setStoreId(1) //change store Id according your needs
->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','url','sku'))
->setPageSize(20);
```

This will get maximum 20 products from store id 1