# Magento ->addCategoryFilter - filtering product collection by root category

Tags: magento

Concerning the use of the **->addCategoryFilter** on a product collection. Why is it not possible to filter by the root category? I have 2 stores, both with different root categories. I want to show a list of best-selling products on my homepage. But I can't filter the products by the root category, only sub-categories under that.

So, on my homepage, all products from both stores show up. I can filter ok by any sub-categories. For example, my second root category has an ID of 35. If I try to filter by this, I get every product from both roots. But the first sub-category under that root is ID 36, and filtering by this works correctly, showing only those products. My call is as follows (simplified):

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(35);

$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addCategoryFilter($_category)
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_testproductCollection->load();

foreach($_testproductCollection as $_testproduct){ 
echo $this->htmlEscape($_testproduct->getName())."<br/>"; 
};
```

Anyone know why this isn't working? Or is there some other way to filter by the root category?

**UPDATE:**
I still haven't had any luck with this. Seems very buggy - adding a category filter using the root category only works sometimes, you need to add all products to the root, then save, then remove any that shouldn't be in that root cat, then re-save. But if you re-index you get all products showing again. If I output the sql query from my above collection call I get the following:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(`price_index`.`tier_price`, LEAST(`price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`), `price_index`.`min_price`) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='2' AND cat_index.category_id='35' INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
```

As you can see, the category is listed there, so why doesn't the filter work?

Comment: I'm digging into a very similar issue. I'm trying to display all products from a category on a CMS page through {{block type="catalog/product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" category_id="1"}}. While I've got 2 Stores that share some products, but also differ in product sets, *all* products are being index into mage_catalog_category_product_index. Runtime, the block I mentioned executes a very similar query to yours, and all products from all shops are returned.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, I think this works, haven't tested too much but seems to have done the trick. You need to first get your stores root category id, then join some fields so you have access to the products "category_id", then filter using that:

```
$_rootcatID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $_rootcatID))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_testproductCollection->load();

foreach($_testproductCollection as $_testproduct){ 
    echo $this->htmlEscape($_testproduct->getName())."<br/>"; 
};
```

Comment: ->joinField('category_id'... this tells it to do a JOIN in the query, to also get the product's category_id. ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id' this part tells it to only get the products whose category ID is the one you want. NOTE: This does not work if System=>Configuration=>Catalog=>Frontend="Use Flat Catalog Product" is set to "Yes."

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar question and ended up answering my question here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24436/product-collection-for-default-category

```
$store_id = 1;
$root_category_id = Mage::app()->getStore(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->getRootCategoryId();

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->setStoreId($store_id);
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($store_id);
$category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category = $category_model->load($root_category_id);
$category->setIsAnchor(true);
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);

echo $collection->getSize(); // example to show you a count of products
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
   ->setVisibility(array(self::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, self::VISIBILITY_BOTH))
   ->addCategoryFilter($_category)
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*');`

Comment: Thanks for that, but I tried already with visibility, and it only works if I specifically set every product in one root category to not be visible in another. Which is a lot of work when there's a lot of products. I don't see why you can't simply filter by a root category.

Comment: Can You give me `SQL` from collection ?

It's strange, cause when i run this:

`$col = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(2))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');` where `2` is root, in my `SQL` i see `INNER JOIN`like this:
`(...) INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.category_id='2' AND cat_index.is_parent=1`.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working. Not sure if it's a Magento bug or not, see update above.

Comment: P.S. You do see the correct category listed in the sql call, but the filter doesn't work (only sometimes after using technique mentioned above, but resets on re-index).

Comment: @Sam, you can try to do same as here :  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069318/magento-addstorefilter-not-working 
Check my latest update.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't try it out, but I have two ideas:

(1) You can try to add an additional store filter to the category:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
     ->addIdFilter(35); 

foreach ($collection as $item) {
     ...
}
```

Which is not very clean because the category_id is hardcoded.

(2) You could also try `addPathFilter()` on the collection (i don't know the root category path by heart, maybe simply "/" - but you can look it up in the database or use getPath() on the loaded root category). Maybe you have to use a store filter, too.

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to filter a product collection, not categories, so those methods won't work. IdFilter will return a product of that ID only. addPathFilter only works with **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection** and not with **Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection**

Answer (score 0):

scenario:

- Magento Version 1.7.0.2
- just one Store
- edited categories in the global mode
- deleted old root-category. So old products had no categories.
- Table "catalog_category_product_index" remains in a bad condition (even after reindexing) and shows to new root-category!

I build a helper-method:

```
    public function getCategoriesId($parent =  -1,$recursionLevel = -1, $asCollection = true)
{
    if($parent === -1){
        $categories = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories(false, true);
    }else{
        $recursionLevel  = ($recursionLevel<0) ? max(0, (int) Mage::app()->getStore()->getConfig('catalog/navigation/max_depth')) : $recursionLevel;
        $categories = $category->getCategories($parent, $recursionLevel, false, $asCollection, true);
    }

    $ids = array();

    foreach($categories as $category){
        if($category->getId()){
            $ids[] = $category->getId();
        }
    }

    return $ids;
}
```

I used the result to filter the categories like jazzhand written:

```
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $_rootcatID))
```

I'm not really sure, if its not just needed for the root-category.