# Magento SQL Query - Filter products by category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, magento-1.6

I've the following SQL query to retrieve products:

```
$query = "SELECT *,m.m_name,m.m_website FROM belvg_countdown c 
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity e ON e.entity_id=c.entity_id
LEFT JOIN manufacturers_products mp ON c.entity_id=mp.product_id
LEFT JOIN manufacturers m ON mp.manufacturers_id=m.manufacturers_id
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(expire_datetime_off , '%Y-%m-%d') > DATE_FORMAT(NOW() , '%Y-%m-%d')
AND DATE_FORMAT(expire_datetime_on , '%Y-%m-%d')!=DATE_FORMAT(NOW() , '%Y-%m-%d')
AND entity_type='product'";
```

Now I'd also add a statement to load only products that are in a category named "featured".
Can you please help me to understand what should I compare/query to get only "featured" products?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See below URL it is very help full to you

[Magento ->addCategoryFilter - filtering product collection by root category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078752/magento-addcategoryfilter-filtering-product-collection-by-root-category)

**or try it**

OK, I think this works, haven't tested too much but seems to have done the trick. You need to first get your stores root category id, then join some fields so you have access to the products "category_id", then filter using that:

```
$_rootcatID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

$_testproductCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $_rootcatID))
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_testproductCollection->load();

foreach($_testproductCollection as $_testproduct){ 
    echo $this->htmlEscape($_testproduct->getName())."<br/>"; 
};
```

Comment: As you can see we also query "belvg_countdown". In fact we select only products that are in a certain range. How can I translate the whole query above using the model? Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all this query to get active product from specificy category.
Use collection.

```
$producs = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(#categoryid or $_category->getId())
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1)
            ->joinField('is_in_stock', 'cataloginventory/stock_item', 'is_in_stock', 'product_id=entity_id', '{{table}}.stock_id=1', 'left');
```

Comment: Hi, the query in my post is tought to work with a countdown extension, that only selects products inside a range of time, for this reason we have a plain sql. Can I use something like that but also using the Inner Join on our custom extension table?

Comment: You can use thar command i showed upside, and on the end of the line, before ; you put this ->getSelect()->__toString(); Now you have the sql query from this collection command.