# Exclude category from collection in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have something like this. What I'm tring to do is to exclude one (or more) category from the list of results.

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'---id or what---','eq'=>'---id of category---'),
));

$_category->getSelect()->order('rand()');
```

Tring this I will get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078752/magento-addcategoryfilter-filtering-product-collection-by-root-category

Comment: instead of "in" use "nin" $collection->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin' => array('finset' => 3,4)))